# Azure billing data API

Tags: powershell, azure, c#-4.0, azure-storage, azure-billing-api

I had created some virtual machine on Azure. Is there any APIs, PowerShell scripts or any other way to get the following information in my ASP.NET application report page.

1. Billing data for individual virtual machine.
2. Usages data for individual virtual machine.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any PowerShell script to download billing excel?

Comment: Any other way to automate the download billing excel process by C# or PowerShell?

Comment: Do you know if the Excel sheet covers only the current period (month) or the entire history of payment details for a subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure does not provide an API for billing/cost metering at the moment. Amazon provides CloudWatch for this.

Windows Azure Pack (for on-premises/SP cloud using Hyper-V) does have an API for cost metering.

The API is one of the most requested features by customers. See this link 
http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/170030-billing/suggestions/1143971-billing-usage-api#comments

I guess Microsoft is working on an API.
So at the moment your only option is downloading the CSV. 
Microsoft recently added a feature which allows to receive email alerts when the monthly costs or total costs reach a customer set threshold.

Comment: Any other way to automate the download billing excel process by C# or PowerShell?

Comment: Microsoft has released APIs for EA Accounts recently, but not yet for individual\non-EA subscriptions.

Comment: Hi Sri Kanth, do you have link to that API?

Answer (score 5):

Azure now provides a way for customers to retrieve their usage and pricing details using the new Azure billing APIs: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-azure-billing-apis-available

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Usage API can be called by customers and partners to get granular Azure resource usage data (hourly and daily buckets), and the response from this REST API is JSON.

Here are some more helpful links:

[High-level article on Azure Billing APIs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-usage-rate-card-overview/)

[Azure Usage API MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/1ea5b323-54bb-423d-916f-190de96c6a3c)

[Azure Billing API code samples on Github](https://github.com/Azure/BillingCodeSamples)

If you have any other questions, please feel free to email me at mobandyo@microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve your Azure resource usage data, there is also a new powershell commandlet that you can avail of: get-UsageAggregates.

Example: 
        Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager

```
    Add-AzureAccount 

    Select-AzureSubscription "YOUR-AZURE-SUB-NAME"

    $agggregate = get-UsageAggregates -ReportedStartTime "5/2/2015" -ReportedEndTime "5/5/2015"
```

Comment: Is there a cmdlet for getting the ratecard info?